# How to make sorted column background of Nautilus list view brighter?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 (I've been using 10.10 before).  First thing I changed in Nautilus was to use list view instead of icon view.  So it looks like this: 
[image: Screenshot]

Please note the dark background of the name column, caused by the column being sorted.  This, for me, is too dark.  The most important information I want to browse through are the names of files and folders, and when it has such a low contrast it means it takes me longer to find the item I am looking for.

**So my question is:** How can I make the background color of the name (sorted) column brighter, like how it was in Ubuntu 10.10?

Also, where can I go to tell the Ubuntu GUI guys "hey this is too dark"?

I've already quickly looked through /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0 but could not find the appropriate setting there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure the same thing.  I'm certain this is controlled by settings in the theme's gtk-3.0 folder, if that helps.  only 2 themes I've found change that. Adwaita is built in theme, for me it makes the selected column background all white. However, there is a nicer result if you change the theme to Zukitwo.  http://lassekongo83.deviantart.com/art/Zukitwo-203936861.  In order to run that, you have to install the murrine theme engine (I think for the gtk-2.0 apps like firefox) and then also the unico engine for the gtk-3.0 apps, like nautilus.

After you do that, the nautilus selected column will be lighter.  I'm trying to find out which if the css settings in that theme make a difference.  I haven't yet figured it out.